# What is it called when a div scrolls as the page scrolls and is there a library written specifically for this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out more information about an element that scrolls within a page as the page is scrolled and has an upper and lower bound.

Specifically, I am trying to add functionality that scrolls my secondary content section (sidebar) within the bounds of my header and footer as the page scrolls.

As an example, Apple uses it in there store when selecting product features to include - http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD093LL/A.

I am able to recreate this functionality, but I'm betting I could find code that has been more thoroughly tested, cross-browser compliant, etc. with stackoverflow's help.

Ideally, I would hope to find something that functions on it's own and not as a part of a much larger library like jQuery.  This is just a preference, but I'm open to potential solutions that include a jQuery-type library...

Comment: Position fixed and http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike Robinson!  A fixed position solution isn't as versatile as I would like (see my response to gilly3's answer), but I'm checking out stickyjs as a possible solution... thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need CSS, `position: fixed`:

```
body
{
    margin-top: 150px; /* header height */
    margin-bottom: 250px; /* footer height */
}
.header, .footer
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.header
{
    top: 0;
}
.footer
{
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This works in all relevant desktop browsers.  It doesn't work in IE6, which is all but extinct, nor will it work in any mobile browser.  In fact, you should use a media query to override these styles for mobile browsers.  Something like this might work:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 500px)
{
    body
    {
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
    .header, .footer
    {
        position: static;  /* or maybe relative */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply gilly3!  I thought about a fixed position, but I was hoping for something more versatile.  For instance, I would like to control the speed and timing of the scroll and when not to scroll (like when the viewport cuts of the bottom of the secondary content).

Comment: So, I did end up using fixed position.  I had to use js to control when to fix the position because the content wasn't meant to stay in exactly the same location while scrolling, but it was a perfect solution... sorry for the tunnel vision yesterday!  Thanks gilly3!